# VNC viewer grey screen.Ubuntu 14.04 and EC2

Tags: 14.04, vnc, amazon-ec2

I followed this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server)

[image: VNC viewer got grey screen]
I can login but I can not see anythings